# MySQLi: Best practice to select all where [column] = # and process

Tags: php, mysqli

I am looking for the best practice for processing this query.  I just want to make sure I am doing it right.

Query:  Need to select all from database table where [column] = # and copy results to another table.

Comment: What you tried till now?

Comment: these are really basic mysql queries .. please try something first then ask here

Comment: I wasn't even thinking when I asked #1.  I removed it.  My brain apparently isn't even processing this late.  My main concern was processing the copy query and I wasn't sure what the best practice was  for that query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE [column] = #

INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3)
(SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE  [column] = #)
```

Comment: The 2nd one was my main query I wasn't sure about.  It must be late and my brain wasn't even processing what I was asking about query #1...haha.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE originaltable;` #*This creates a new table just like original table*

`INSERT INTO newtable (SELECT * FROM originaltable WHERE column = '#');` #*this moves selected records from original table to new created table*